# If match error when a value does not match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have this:
`=IF(MATCH("Example",D:D,0),"Not Available","Available")`. The problem is that if the value isn't in the column, it gives the #N/A error. How do I make that go away? I have read several similar problems that might have had the solution but couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: Put `ISERROR` like this: `IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Example",D:D,0)),"Not Available","Available")`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple. Thanks Again

Comment: @L42: It's a valid answer :) You might wanna put that as an answer ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout haha it's short so i just commented it. what's important is we've helped someone.

Comment: @L42: Perhaps a small description of what `Iserror` does + your solution? Might help someone else in the future... Just saying ;)

Answer (score 6):

Although I've commented it out, here's the formal answer to the question.

The reason why your function is throwing up an #N/A error value is because
the `logical` part of your `IF` statement cannont handle values other than `Bolean` (true or false).
When `MATCH` returns an ERROR, the `logical` part of `IF` statement was not satisfied
thus returning #N/A error.
To correct this, we add `ISERROR` on your `IF` statement like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Example",D:D,0)),"Not Available","Available")
```

`ISERROR` evaluates if the function or statement returns an ERROR.
It returns `TRUE` if it is an ERROR and `FALSE` otherwise.
Adding that to your code let's your `IF` statement evaluates the result of `MATCH` function when it returns an ERROR.